# Struct inside a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

This is a code snippet of an example coding that my lecturer sent.
I don't know about the logic. Please bear with me, I am currently learning my way as a Computer Science student. Edit: It seems like this is a linked list.

```
struct db {
    int value;
    struct db *next;
} *head, *tail, *curr;

void pushF()
{
    int input;
    system("CLS");
    printf("\n\n\tInput value: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    curr = (struct db*) malloc(sizeof(struct db));
    curr->value = input;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail = curr;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
    }
}
```

If input is 1,
My best guess is:

- each of the struct name (head, tail and curr) all have three different "int value" and (`struct data *next`) - **I don't understand**
- the program starts off with a prompt to input value
- `curr = (struct db*) malloc(sizeof(struct db));` **I don't understand**
- sets the integer value of `curr` to 1
- if head is `NULL` then.. **I don't understand**
- `head = tail = curr` - **I don't understand**. My best guess is this is a chain.
- sets the pointer next on head to `NULL`.
- else sets the pointer next on `curr` to head and sets head to `curr`.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: as a side point - research why you should not cast the result of an allocation.  I realize that this came from your lecturer, but s/he is wrong for doing this.

Comment: @ChrisTurner an explanation of what is happening.

Comment: Question is too broad and there are clearly multiple concepts you don't understand. Start by reading your notes / text book. Come back with directed questions if you still have any. For example: _curr = (struct db*) malloc(sizeof(struct db)); [to be honest, i don't know what this line does. it just doesn't make any sense to me.]_ - this is a question in itself.

Comment: This is a badly-written linked list implementation of a stack data structure.  Each node in the list (an instance of `struct db`) represents an entry on the stack.  The `value` member stores the value associated with the node, while the `next` member explicitly points to the next element in the list.  Each time you call `pushF`, a new `struct db` object is dynamically allocated with `malloc`, and the input value is written to the `value` member.  This new node becomes the head of the list (top of the stack).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an example of a struct within a struct. Instead, struct db *next just declares the struct member `next` to be a pointer to a `struct db` .

> each of the struct name (head, tail and curr) all have three different "int value" and (`struct data *next`)

The code creates 3 "instances" pointers to struct, head (pointer to first node of list), curr (current node), tail (pointer to last node of list).

> curr = (struct db*) malloc(sizeof(struct db));

Allocates memory space for one node.

> sets the integer value of `curr` to 1

It sets curr->value to 1.

> if head is `NULL` ... head = tail = curr

If the list was empty, it sets head and tail to the only node in the list.

> sets the pointer next on head to `NULL`.

Not a good way to do this, it would be better to set curr->next == NULL, to make it easier to understand.

> sets the pointer next on `curr` to head and sets head to `curr`.

This is done to insert the current node to the beginning of a list. Assume the list starts off with one node `A`, then you have:

```
head -> A
A -> NULL   (A.next = NULL)
tail -> A
```

Then assume you insert a node B, after this you have:

```
head -> B
B -> A      (B.next = &A)
A -> NULL   (A.next = NULL)
tail -> A
```